# 'CC_MD5' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - This function is cryptographically broken and should。。。。

Tags: ios

CC_MD5 has been deprecated in ios14 but my project supports ios14 at least. I still need MD5. What should I do? The development language I use is OC

Comment: If only your project support below iOS 13  you can use CC_MD5. CC_MD5 is deprecated from iOS 13 to higher version.

Comment: It isn't that you *can't* use MD5, it is that you *shouldn't* regardless of iOS version. MD5 is broken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MD5 is deprecated because it's a flawed, insecure algorithm. If you can, avoid it. But if have to use MD5 because the algorithm is given by old data or by outside requirements, you can continue to use.

The compiler generates a warning. But you can still use `CC_MD5`. And I doubt that Apple will ever remove it as it is used in too many existing applications.

You can selectively suppress the warning in Objective-C:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

- (void) hashData
{
    // your code using CC_MD5
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: The million dollar question is: How do I get rid of the deprecation warning in Swift?

Comment: With the pragma directive shown above. They work for the clang compiler (default for Xcode). Are you using a different compiler?

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer only works for ObjC, because Swift doesn't support `#pragma`.

Additionally, the entire `CommonCrypto` framework is outdated and superceded by the `CryptoKit` framework.

Here's a solution in Swift using `CryptoKit`:

```
import CryptoKit

let data:String = "the data to be hashed"
let messageData = string.data(using: .utf8)!
let digestData = Insecure.MD5.hash (data: messageData)
let digestHex = String(digestData.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined().prefix(32))
```